Error al crear un arreglo de objetos
que tal, me dejaron como tarea realizar un sistema de una empresa de logistica, por ahora, estoy trabajando con MVC y tkinter.
Tengo una tabla llamada "transportes", en donde ingrese datos ficticios. Por ahora, solo estoy realizando un modelo para este, es decir, una clase en donde al crear un objeto se inicialicen datos relacionados a los de la base de datos.

Esta es mi base de datos.
A continuacion, es mi clase donde pongo metodos relacionado con ese registro.
class transporteModel:

tabla_db = 'transportes'
columnas_db = 'tra_nombre', 'tra_cantidad', 'tra_disponible', 'tra_costo', 'tra_tipo'
atributos = dict()

db = database.conexion_db()
cursor = db.cursor()

def __init__(self, id=None, nombre=None, cantidad=None, disponible=None, costo=None, tipo=None):
    self.atributos['tra_id'] = id
    self.atributos['tra_nombre'] = nombre
    self.atributos['tra_cantidad'] = cantidad
    self.atributos['tra_disponible'] = disponible
    self.atributos['tra_costo'] = costo
    self.atributos['tra_tipo'] = tipo
    
def printTransporte(self):
    for atributo, valor in self.atributos.items():
        print(f'{atributo}-> {valor}')
    print('\n')

def allTransportes(self):
    query = f'SELECT * FROM {self.tabla_db}'
    transportes = self.consultaSQL(query)
    
    return transportes
    
def consultaSQL(self, query):
    registros = []
            
    self.cursor.execute(query)
    
    resultado = self.cursor.fetchall()

    for registro in resultado:
        transporte = transporteModel(registro[0],
                                     registro[1],
                                     registro[2],
                                     registro[3],
                                     registro[4],
                                     registro[5]
                                    )
        registros.append(transporte.atributos)
        
    for atributo in registros:
        print(atributo, '\n')

Como se ve, al final, intento imprimir los atributos de cada objeto, pero al imprimirlo me regresa el ultimo dato de la base de datos.

No entiendo por que, si ya intente imprimir los datos por cada uno y se supone que si crea el objeto con los datos correspondientes.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! algun experto en python seguro lo va a tener mas claro.. y python es medio raro para muchas cosas.. pero en cualquier otro lenguaje OOP, ese codigo guarda siempre el ultimo valor en todas las instancias del objeto, porque nunca le estas diciendo que es nueevo... peroooooo esto es python, y le puedo estar pifiando... fijate por ese lado...

Lo que está pasando, a resumidas cuentas, es un problema relacionado con la herencia de clases en el que todas tus instancias de transporteModel "comparten" el mismo diccionario. Eso significa que al intentar modificar "uno de los diccionarios" vas a modificar los demás.
¿Por que sucede esto?
Cuando accedes a un atributo, lo que en realidad hace Python es buscar dicho en el siguiente orden:

Instancia
Clase que creó la instancia
Clase padre
Clase "abuelo"
...
metaclase, habitualmente type

Hasta encontrarlo. En caso contrario, manda error.
Esto, aplicado a [transporteModelInstancia].atributos[key] = value se da de la siguiente manera:

Busca el atributo atributos de la instancia de transporteModel. Al no tener el atributo...
Recurre a transporteModel, que tiene el atributo atributos con el diccionario.
Establece la clave key con el valor value en el diccionario

Solución
La solución es crear el diccionario dentro de la propia instancia usando el constructor:
...
def __init__(self, id=None, ...):
    self.attributos = {"tra_id":id, ...}
    ...

De tal manera, cada ejecución del constructor creará un nuevo diccionario y se lo asignará a la instancia correspondiente.

MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS, ya me parecia raro este problema y como lo has explicado queda clarisimo. Muchas gracias en verdad!
